# Варианты разбивки слишком большого запроса SQL

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

У нас есть SQL сервер в котором стоит ограничение по размеру SQL запроса ~200кб. Я столкнулся с задачей поменять подход к получению данных через SELECT запрос куда передаётся большое количество ID для WHERE IN параметра, настолько большое что он исчерпывает ограничения на сервере.

Пока что я придумал следующие варианты обхода этого ограничения, буду признателен если можете подсказать ещё:

1. Создавать временную таблицу и туда вставить необходимые ID значения **поблочно** (опять-таки чтобы не упереться в ограничение), а потом делать SELECT из неё внутри WHERE IN.
2. Передать с запросом max_query_size с большим значением благо драйвер это позволяет
3. Сделать поблочные запросы в изначальном SQL, что вряд ли возможно так как там используется группировка и агрегация.

Comment: Узнайте, чем определены именно такие ограничения, и возможно ли их изменение для отдельного соединения, не приведёт ли это к проблемам. Если всё ок, меняйте установки для соединения.

Comment: Как часто меняется перечень ID. Непредсказуемо он меняется от запроса к запросу или есть в нем логика. Это я к тому есть ли возможность хранить список в БД перманентно, немного модифицируя со временем. Что бы не перезаливать его целиком для каждого запроса

Comment: что вы используете ClickHouse, mysql or smth else?

Comment: Используется Clickhouse (на основе MySQL движка) для предоставления отчетности по нажатиям на рекламные блоки, так что список ID меняется, но насколько - не знаю, уточню.

Comment: @Mike, перечень ID меняется в зависимости от товаров, выбранных продавцом для продажи. Список можно сохранить в ClickHouse, но проблема в том что он хранится в другой БД. Кросс-БД взаимодействие можно использовать в ClickHouse через file, создавая временную таблицу, но, к сожалению, не через shared memory/Redis/memcache хранилища.

Comment: @Akina, текущие настройки - для максимальной скорости, их можно поменять, но это отразится и на остальных частях, работающих с ClickHouse. Можно поменять эту настройку конкректно для этого запроса, как своеобразный костыль.

Comment: А где вы сейчас по факту держите этот список id и как часто обновляете. В той "другой БД" нет средств сообщать об изменениях ? Не думаю, что продавцы ежесекундно меняют свои списки товаров. В идеале, раз уж речь про "поменять подход", я бы всеми силами постарался сделать так что бы список ID с ID продавца оказался и постоянно хранился в той БД на которой непосредственно выполняется запрос, что бы можно было сделать тупо `where id in(select id from ...)` или join